# How to use Reference Types with wasm-bindgen

Tags: wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm, wasm-pack

First of all, I'm newby in rust and webassembly. I'd like to use Reference Types with wasm-bindgen, following theexample in wasm-bindgen book [Support for Reference Types](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/reference-types.html#support-for-reference-types)

I've tried to build my code with the reference types flag

```
wasm-pack build --reference-types
```

But I'm getting following error

> error: Found argument '--reference-types' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

I've installed rustc with version 1.55 and wasm-pack with version 0.10.1.

Am I missing any thing?

Comment: Could seem like `wasm-pack` don't support `--reference-types`, but `wasm-bindgen-cli` (https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/cli.html#--reference-types)` does. Only use `wasm-pack`, but think similar could be obtained with `wasm-bindgen-cli` command.

Comment: Thanks @JonasBojesen. It seems I have to use wasm-bindgen command after building with wasm-pack. Still i'0m getting some error. Guess I need some more ork/research